# GUI tools for Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface

I need a favour. I want to develop a software that have custom `titlesbar`, custom `toolbar`, custom `menubar` or something like this. So is there any GUI development tools for Visual Studio?

Comment: What Visual Studio do you want to use? Do you want to develop in C# or Visual Basic? The software is a desktop application or a web application? Please give more details. Visual Studio offers many type of projects, like Windows Forms Application, that aid you in making friendly user interfaces with many customizable elements.

Comment: i what to develop desktop application with visual Basic. it is better to develop Windows Forms Application. Bellow link i give a screen short that i want to develop. http://www.friendsbook.net/images.png